# How to split the text and number here

Tags: python, pandas

I have a the below column which is in python dataframe

[image]

But, the expected output should be like

[image]

Any help in Python please?

Comment: Where did that extra colon come from in `1:10:800`? Can you please share this data as text instead of picture? No one wants to have to transcribe to replicate on their own machine.

Comment: Thank you so much for you commet JNevill. I will not be able to share the complete information regarding this. But there are certain rows, which are like this in the dataframe and this is raw data file and more cleaning is required and this is where I struck.

Comment: Copy/Paste the exact cells you've shared with us already, but formatted as text, rather than an image... @Pavan

Comment: So @OP you can't even do the minimum and share a sample? Like I said, few people are going to generate a DF on their machine transcribing your data just to answer a question on stackoverflow. It's not like we are being paid. Perhaps you'll get lucky, but help us out here a bit. Screenshots are the worst way of sharing data.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question whether `words` contains strings with brackets in them or lists of one string each, so here are solutions for both cases.

**DataFrame containing strings including square brackets:**

```py
pat='\[(.*\d) (.*)\]'
#pat='\[((?: *[^ ]+)+?) +((?:[a-zA-Z]+ *)+)\]'
df = df.words.str.extract(pat).rename(columns={0:'numbers',1:'text'})
```

Input:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
'words':['[4,25 l Dose]','[850 ml Dose]','[1 : 10 800 ml Dose]','[5 x 200 Schrumpfpackung]']
})
```

Output:

```
      numbers             text
0        4,25           l Dose
1         850          ml Dose
2  1 : 10 800          ml Dose
3     5 x 200  Schrumpfpackung
```

Explanation:

- using the [`Series.str()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor and [`extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), extract the capture groups from the string in each item as two columns corresponding to `numbers` and `text` columns
- rename the auto-generated columns labeled `0` and `1` to have the desired labels (`numbers` and `text`).

**DataFrame containing lists with one string each:**

```py
pat='(.*\d) (.*)'
#pat='((?: *[^ ]+)+?) +((?:[a-zA-Z]+ *)+)'
df = df.words.str.get(0).str.extract(pat).rename(columns={0:'numbers',1:'text'})
```

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'words':[['4,25 l Dose'],['850 ml Dose'],['1 : 10 800 ml Dose'],['5 x 200 Schrumpfpackung']]
})
```

Output

```
same as above ...
```

Explanation:

- using the [`Series.str()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor to manipulate each element of type `list` (slightly confusing as the accessor is named `str()` but is more generally applicable to pandas Series whose values are python sequences, including both `str` and `list`) and [`get()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html), access the first (and only) string in each `list` in the columns
- use [`extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the capture groups from the string in each item as two columns corresponding to `numbers` and `text` columns
- rename the auto-generated columns labeled `0` and `1` to have the desired labels (`numbers` and `text`).

---

Note that either the `pat` used above or the one that is commented out will work for each respective case (string or list). I started with the commented-out pattern, but the pattern in the answer by @Pieter Geelen seems to work as well and is simpler, so I have included it (and a variant of it) above.

Answer (score 2):

You can first extract value from the list with [`pandas.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and then use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

```
df['words'] = df['words'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df = df.join(df['words'].str.extract(r'(.*\d) (.*)')
            ).rename(columns = {1:'text', 0:'numbers'}
                    ).drop(columns='words')
print(df)
```

---

```
     numbers             text
0       4,25           I Dose
1        850          ml Dose
2  1: 10 800          ml Dose
3    1 x 390             Dose
4    5 x 200  Schrumpfpachung
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try out Regex
With the pattern: `(.*\d) (.*)` you can already outline that you should have something that ends with a number, that is trailed with some describtion in words.

```
import re
some_strings = """4,25 l Dose
850 ml Dose
1: 10 800 ml Dose
1 x 390 Dose 
5 x 200 Schrumpfverpackung """.split('\n')

for item in some_strings:
    m = re.search("(.*\d) (.*)", item)
    print(m.group(0))
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
```

That prints out

```
4,25 l Dose
4,25
l Dose
850 ml Dose
850
ml Dose
1: 10 800 ml Dose
1: 10 800
ml Dose
1 x 390 Dose 
1 x 390
Dose 
5 x 200 Schrumpfverpackung 
5 x 200
Schrumpfverpackung
```

#### EDIT

For a pandas series you need to note that you need the `iteritems` method and use the second item in the tuple, as the first is the index itself.

```
import re
some_strings = pd.Series("""4,25 l Dose
850 ml Dose
1: 10 800 ml Dose
1 x 390 Dose 
5 x 200 Schrumpfverpackung """.split('\n'))

for item in some_strings.iteritems():
    m = re.search("(.*\d) (.*)", item[1])
    print("first group:", m.group(0))
    print("second group:", m.group(1))
    print("third group:", m.group(2))
```

Comment: Hi Pieter, as I have seen that you have used as string, and worked it out, which is great. But the problem here is the length of the column is almost 18000, and I have converted the Series datatype to String and tried and it did not worked as it is showing me an error as follows:

-----------------------------------Code-----------------------------

some_strings = df['words']

for item in some_strings:
    re.search("(.*\d) (.*)", item)

----------------------------------- Error------------------------------

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I added a pandas series example :)